# The best practice to load Hibernate entity when submit data using Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Give two entities, Movie and Director.

@Entity

```
public class Movie extends BaseEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1545404740388837658L;

  @Column(name="movieName", nullable=false, length=200)
  private String movieName;

  @Column(name="year", nullable=false)
  private Integer year; 

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="director_id")
  private Director director;

  //setter, getter
}

@Entity
public class Director extends BaseEntity {

  @NotEmpty
  @Column(nullable = false, length=50)
  private String name;

  //setter, getter 
}
```

And there is a form in JSP

```
<form:form action="saveMovie" commandName="movie" >
    <p><label>Movie Name</label><form:input path="movieName" /></p> 
    <p><label>Year</label><form:input path="year" /></p>
    <p><label>Director</label><form:input id="txtDirector" path="director.id" /></p> 


    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="Save" />
    </p>
  </form:form>
```

This is the original controller without Director handling

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveMovie", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveMovie(@ModelAttribute Movie movie, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, ModelMap model) {


    getMovieModel().saveMovie(movie); //get a DAO to persist a Movie

    List<Movie> movies = getMovieModel().getAllMovies(); //reload all Movies
    model.put("allMovies", movies);
    return "test/allMovies";
  }
```

What is the best pattern to load an existing Director entity when a Movie is submitted?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly you want?

Comment: Hi Japs, If Moive is a new entity to be inserted, but Director already exists in database(Director is selected in client view page), how do I make sure Director is going to be update rather than insert a new one?

Answer (score 0):

If Director is mandatory for Movie then it is better to load using FetchType = EAGER.
Also if you are required Director object for each Movie entity for some logic, then it is better to use EAGER.

If you use FetchType = LAZY then, it will fetch Director entity when you call movie.getDirector() method.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out an solution, but not sure it is a best pattern of "associating a existing entity to a new entity which is going to be persisted into database" within Spring MVC model.

Here is my code revision:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveMovie", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String saveMovie(@ModelAttribute("movie") Movie movie, @ModelAttribute("director") Director director, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, ModelMap model) { 
    /*please note that parameter "director" is newly added */
    logger.trace(movie.getMovieName() + "," + movie.getYear());
    movie.setDirector(director); // <-- newly added
    getMovieModel().saveMovie(movie);

    List<Movie> movies = getMovieModel().getAllMovies();
    model.put("allMovies", movies);
    return "test/allMovies";
  }

  @ModelAttribute("director") 
  public Director loadDirector(@RequestParam(value="director.id", required=false) Long id) {

    Director director = null;
    if (id != null) 
      director = getDirectorModel().loadDirector(id);
    return director;
  }
```

Please see method "loadDirector" is annotated @ModelAttribute, so that before every time controller is being called, loadDirector() is called first. I can check request parameter "director.id" is null or not. 
If director id is not null, I can load a Director from database, so that it can be used when saveMovie() is called. 
Don't forget to call

```
movie.setDirector(director);
```

in saveMovie() method.